# Print high resolution images from browser?

Tags: browsers, print, images

I have a packing slip that is generated with each order that I want to print and place in each shipped package. The images on the packing slip will not change and need to be high resolution for crisp printing.

My issue occurs because I need to print out of my web browser which enlarges the size of the images because of the 300 ppi density change to web standard 72 ppi.

How can I specify 300 ppi on the images needed to be printed in my browser while keeping them the correct size on paper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well...

This is not the real answer for what you want, but internet is not primary intended for this kind of printing. Usually when a website wanna make printing available, they give PDFs and high quality JPEGs for download and print.

Answer (score 1):

While Dave is right, you can `Creatively Avoid the Entire Resolution Problem` by using **SVG**: ever heard of Vector Artworks? Pretty nice, and... Very matured over the years and also very supported (including in IE 9)

This will print anything better, much better than 300 dpi, as the printer will always print vector artwork sharper directly calculated natively in the printer. Wikipedia has a good page on SVG. I am using SVGZ (compressed) which is not only sharper, but like SVG, much smaller in kbytes than raster.

`Now THATS something which is good on the internet: saving filesize while using smart ways to render neat graphics.`

Comment: PDF is also a vector format if you use it properly.

Comment: Interesting solution, with the few drawbacks - only IE 9 supports it partially, IE8 oe earlier don't. Despite other browsers support it, the rendering may be slightly different due different implementations (if they can't render even CSS properly, you can imagine a lesser know and used spec). The quality should be about the same as PDF, hence PDF also is vectorial (PDF has broader advantages for quality control, and has better support in the wild).

Comment: Very nice. I will give this a go. Because dynamically created print slips are generated, pdf is not a possible solution. Thanks!

Comment: PDF files can be created dynamically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651011/dynamic-pdf-generation